# iosアプリプッシュ通知されるデバイスとされないデバイス

Tags: ios

現在開発中のアプリでプッシュ通知、通知センターにて通知されるデバイスとされないデバイスがあります。
以下がテストした条件ですが、考えられる原因を教えて頂けると助かります。
断定できなくとも可能性として考えられる原因でめ結構です。

通知の仕組み
①ユーザーが時間を設定
②サイレントプッシュを通知
③アプリ側からサーバーにアクセスして更新情報を取得
④更新情報をプッシュ通知、通知センターへ表示

通知について

アプリ起動時（フォアグランド）
iphone 6       ◯
iphone 6- 2  ◯
iphone 6-3  ◯
iphone6s      ◯
iphone7        ×
iphone7       ×

アプリ終了（バックグランド）
iphone 6       ◯
iphone 6- 2  ×
iphone 6-3  ×
iphone6s      ◯
iphone7        ×
iphone7       ×

iphoneスリープ（バックグランド）
iphone 6       ◯
iphone 6- 2  ×
iphone 6-3  ×
iphone6s      ◯
iphone7        ×
iphone7       ×

バージョン
iphone 6       10.3.1
iphone 6- 2  10.3.1
iphone 6-3    10.2.1
iphone6s      10.3.1
iphone7        10.3.1
iphone7       10.3.1

その他の条件
全て通知設定はオンになっています
testflightよりインストール
合計6台にインストール
iphone6は3台
4G回線、wifi環境ともに結果は同じ

Comment: 私の経験だとそもそもサイレントプッシュはアプリが終了している場合、届かなかったと思います。また、Appleはプッシュ通知が100%届くことは保証していなかったと思います。因みに、今回、届かないと言っているプッシュ通知は2と4のどちらを指してますでしょうか？

Comment: ご返信ありがとうございます。
断定は出来ないのですが④において通知されるデバイスがあるため②は通知されているものと推測しています。
また、全ての通知を受信できているデバイスは何度テストをしても④の通知があるのですが、逆にテストで全く通知されないデバイスは何回テストをしても④の通知を受信できません。

サイレントプッシュ通知はタスクを切らずバックグランド状態の際に受信しており、受信をトリガーにバックグランド更新をしています。
完全にアプリが終了している際は表記した一切のタスクは機能していません。

Comment: ご説明ありがとうございます。理由を特定するために、確実に1つずつ状況を整理していくのが良いかと思います。1番はデバッグしながら動作確認するのが良いと思いますが、testflightという状況から察するにローカル環境では発生していないのかなと推測します。であるならば、②でサイレントプッシュ受信時にNSUserDefaultにログ保存するなど一時的に処理を追加すれば動作が追えるかと思います。また、③でサーバアクセスしているのであれば、サーバのアクセスログを確認することで③まで動作しているか証明できるかと思います。サービス固有のロジックが影響している可能性があるのであれば、プッシュ通知が届かない端末のデバイストークンにロジックを介さない形で直接プッシュ通知を送ってみても良いかもしれません。(単純にプッシュ通知を送るだけのサーバを立てて試すなど)もし、この時点で届かないのであれば、デバイストークンがおかしいということが言えるかと思います。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/75373

Answer (score 0):

1点指摘するとすれば、 `registerForRemoteNotifications`の実行位置でしょうか。

```
if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_9_x_Max) {
    // iOS9以下
    UIUserNotificationType types = UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert;
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
} else {
    // iOS10以上
    UNAuthorizationOptions options = UNAuthorizationOptionAlert | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge | UNAuthorizationOptionSound;
    [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] requestAuthorizationWithOptions:options completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (granted) {
            // 通知が許可された or されている場合
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
        }
    }];
    [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] setDelegate:self];
}
```

iOS10以降は`requestAuthoricationWithOptions`を実行して、ユーザに通知許可アラートを表示するようになっています。
この結果が`granted`に入ってくるので、ユーザが明示的に通知許可した場合のみ`registerForRemoteNotifications`を実行しましょう。

Answer (score -1):

ご返信ありがとうございます。
細かく指示を頂けましたので原因を見つける手掛かりとなりそうで大変感謝いたします。
まずはサーバーのログを取るようにして原因を特定してみたいと思います。

そしてこの問題に対してこのようなコードを作成したのですがどう思いますか？

```
if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_9_x_Max) {
        UIUserNotificationType allNotificationTypes =
        (UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);
        UIUserNotificationSettings *settings =
        [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:allNotificationTypes categories:nil];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    } else {
        // iOS 10 or later

        UNAuthorizationOptions authOptions =
        UNAuthorizationOptionAlert
        | UNAuthorizationOptionSound
        | UNAuthorizationOptionBadge;
        [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter]
         requestAuthorizationWithOptions:authOptions
         completionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError * _Nullable error) {
         }
         ];

        // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
        [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] setDelegate:self];
        // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)

    }

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
```

Comment: 「どう思うか？」とは使用方法が正しいかという話でしょうか？？

Comment: ご返答ありがとうございます。仰る通り使用方法として正しいものなのでしょうか？

Comment: コードベースになるため、回答に記載しました

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。早速試させて頂きたいと思います。

Comment: これは自己回答なのですか？もし追記情報なら質問内容の方に移してください。回答であれば、回答として「どういったコードなのか」簡単に説明すると更に良い回答となります。